# Is there any Crystal Reports object that works like DIV in HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Hi,

I am new to Crystal Reports. I am using Crystal Reports in my .NET Application to generate Point of Purchase (POP) for my customers. I want to be able to generate something like this with exact width and height : [image: One Record from the Database]

I was using HTML to generate a PDF file for my sample. Then I decided to you use Crystal Reports. How can I have something like a DIV in Crystal Reports to work as a container? The contents will be generated from the database so I need to be able to control the flow of the element. For example, having CSS property overflow  : hidden. Does Crystal Reports support this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why did you abandon using a PDF and go to Crystal Reports?

Comment: @KenCenerelli  I want a tool that help me to control the layout of my sample easily. As I mentioned earlier  I used  html, but I could not find a tool that generate a PDF from html and helps to control the layout of the PDF easily for one case. Also this sample will be inserted from employees that have not html and css knowledge. So crystal report makes it easy for you. But I could not find an object that works like a div.

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with such a control in CR. I did find this thread (http://forums.asp.net/t/1209306.aspx) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

you can add css to your crystal report and i think it can help you so much because of your background in html but if you want to use c# codes the thing which can i offer you is working with sections, you can add new object with left and top and height and width of that objects for example you can add an ole object or field object or text object or subreport object like this:

```
                CRAXDRT.Report report2 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
                CRAXDRT.Application app2 = new CRAXDRT.Application();
                report2 = app2.OpenReport("Test.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);

                CRAXDRT.TextObject to3 = report2.Sections[i].AddTextObject("This is text object sample", 0, 0);
                to3.Left = 100;
                to3.Top = 20;
                to3.Height = 100;
                to3.Width = 200;
                to3.HorAlignment = CRAXDRT.CRAlignment.crHorCenterAlign;
```

this is just text object sample and you can add other objects same as this sample, i hope it can help you.